# How to wrap iterator of library class to catch NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, iterator, nosuchelementexception

Let's say I have a class that is holding an object that is an iterable. Now for some reason, I want to "wrap" this iterator so that when there is nothing more to iterate over, instead of crashing because of `NoSuchElementException`, we are returned `null` instead. With for example an `ArrayList`, this is easy, because I can just save a `index` property on my class. But with for example a `TreeSet`, it's more tricky, because there is no way as far as I know to use an index. How can I accomplish this with a TreeSet? Is there some way to catch the exception somewhere?

My class holding the iterable would be:

```
public class MyClass{
    TreeSet<Integer> list = new TreeSet<Integer>();
   // Do something so that list.iterator() returns null when getting NoSuchElementException
}
```

And I could use it like:

```
MyClass myObj = new MyClass();
Iterator myIter = myObj.iterator();
iterObj = myIter.next();
while(iterObj != null){
    //do stuff
}
```

Of course I could catch the exception outside of the class, but doing so in multiple places will result in a lot of try and catch statements.

Please don't tell me I can use a foreach loop, it's not possible in my application.

**EDIT**: Here's why I can't use `hasNext()`:

I have two iterators listA and listB.

Here's the original algorithm:

```
    pA = listA.next(); // null if !hasNext()
    pB = listB.next(); // null if !hasNext()
    while(pA != null && pB != null){

        if(pA.docID == pB.docID){
            // do stuff
            pA = listA.next();
            pB = listB.next();
        }   

        else if(pA.docID < pB.docID){
            pA = listA.next();
        }   
        else{
            pB = listB.next();
        }   
    }
```

I'm unable to find a way to implement the same functionality using `hasNext()`. Here's an attempt:

```
while (listA.hasNext() && listB.hasNext()){
    pA = listA.next();
    pB = listB.next();
    if(pA.docID == pB.docID){
        // do stuff
    }
    else if(pA.docID < pB.docID){
        pA = listA.next();
    }   
    else{
        pB = listB.next();
    }       
}
```

But it obviously isn't the same algorithm, we will iterate two times on one of `listA` or `listB` whenever we don't have `pA.docID == pB.docID`. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Eugh. Why? Just use `Collection.forEach`. One of the challenges with writing maintainable code is getting rid of `null`, not adding _more_ `null`.

Comment: you can use `hasNext()` method to avoid `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: Boris, As I said, it's not suitable in my application since I need to handle next() calls manually.

Comment: I don't know what handling things _manually_ means in terms of programming - these two concepts are orthogonal.

Comment: `while(iterObj != null)` - question; what happens when the `Collection` has `null` _in it_?

Comment: Boris, that's not meant to happen.

Comment: Given your fondness for `null` can you be _sure_? It seems to me that you are working around some problem (that you haven't explained to us) and creating about 200 more.

Comment: I'm guessing your point is that I can't. Are you suggesting I change my algorithm so that the while loop condition is `(myIter.hasNext())` instead?

Comment: That would be the canonical way to use an `Iterator` - and with good reason.

Comment: Boris, I've attempted this, but I've been unsuccessful. I've detailed my problem in an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to be able to iterate with returning `null` instead of throwing `Exception`s. While this isn't as favorable typically as using Ravi's solution, I have attempted to be creative and meet your needs by generically wrapping the iterator.

Unless this is an assignment, follow Ravi's advice. There is a reason control flow is implemented in Java. Workarounds like this are usually discouraged.

```
public class MyClass {

   public static class MyIterator<T> {
      Iterator<T> defaultIterator;

      public MyIterator(Iterator<T> defaultIterator) {
         this.defaultIterator = defaultIterator;
      }

      public T getNext() {
         try {
            if (defaultIterator.hasNext()) {
               return defaultIterator.next();
            }
         } catch (Exception e) {
            // Fall through
         }
         return null;
      }
   }

   public static void Main(String[] args) {
      TreeSet<Integer> list = new TreeSet<>();

      MyIterator<Integer> myIterator = new MyIterator<>(list.iterator());

      while (myIterator.getNext() != null) {
         // do stuff
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It is an assignment. We're meant to copy a pseudocode algorithm from the course book. I've detailed the exact problem with using `hasNext()` in an edit.

Answer (score 1):

In case you really want to catch this exception when no more elements, then this is one of examples how it could be done:

public class MyClass {
        private final Set list = new TreeSet<>();

```
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator();
        return new Iterator<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return it.hasNext();
            }

            @Override
            public Integer next() {
                try {
                    return it.next();
                } catch (NoSuchElementException ignored) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        MyClass myObj = new MyClass();
        Iterator<Integer> myIter = myObj.iterator();
        Integer iterObj = myIter.next();
        while (iterObj != null) {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

But I strongly recommend you to check existed element before retrieve this element from iterator:

```
Iterator<Integer> it = muObject.iterator();

while(it.hasNext()) {
    Integer value = it.next:
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: It isn't possible to use `hasNext()` for me, at least to the best of my ability. I've explained why in an edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`hasNext()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#hasNext--) instead of directly calling `myIter.next()`

```
if (myIter.hasNext ())
{
   iterObj = myIter.next();
   ...
}
else
{
   return null;
}
```

Comment: True, but it doesn't save any clutter compared to catching exceptions, which was the purpose of the question

Comment: @Sahand well, it doesn't use exceptions for flow control - another thing we try and avoid. Are you telling us that you are writing code that uses exceptions for flow control and then returns `null`? Wow. That sounds ... terrible.

Comment: @Sahand I don't know, what are talking about. I explained why are you getting `NoSuchElementException` and what has to be done